# Odd permissions issues on Windows Share

Tags: windows, sharing, permission, file-sharing, smb

*I'm handling the IT for a Mac based design studio and they're having weird issues with files on a Windows Server 2008 R2 server. They should have complete access to everything, they can create, delete, edit files but sometimes they can't move them or rename them. It seems to be limited to files they created but I'm not 100%, anyone come across this before?*

Edit:
On further investigation, it's not permissions it's file locking. Some programs including preview or opening files (assuming locking them) and not releasing. Killing all the programs or remounting the share sees to working but it's a workaround that's not really acceptable to the users.

Comment: has any progress been made on this topic?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: For those that are still looking into the issue. I spent about 3 months trying to solve this problem. The shares were probably good enough for casual use but the site required that designers could work directly for the share and a locking issue could result in the loss of a days work. I sent a lot of time trying to diagnose the issue. I found it was finder itself that was causing it and I could kill that finder process to temperately solve the issue and allow them to save but that wasn't acceptable. In the end we gave up and bought this product
ExtremeZ-IP. I'm out of characters.

Answer (score 1):

Feels a bit cheeky answering my own question but I've spent enough time searching through boards that don't go anywhere to know how frustrating that can be.
It's not a permissions issues, I like a lot people assumed it was a permissions issue. It's file locking. The Mac opens a file that's hosted on the server and closes it, but the directory above the directory the file is contained in stays open. It's this directory that can't be moved or renamed. To close the connection you can unmount and remount the share drive, or you can kill finder, or on windows server you can Right Click on Computer, Select Manage, Expand Roles, Expand File Services, click on Share and Storage Managment. Then click Action from the menu at the top, then Manage Open Files. That will bring up a dialogue showing all the open files on the computer, I like to order by open file so I can see the file paths in order. Select the problem folder(s) and click close selected.
The latter open sounds harder but once the dialog is open it's easier to manage if you have a lot of users.

This is still not a solution, it's a workaround but I thought I could help someone else search.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you are using the SMB/CIFS (Samba) protocol when connecting using Finder.

Try typing `cifs://` instead of `smb://`

Comment: I'm using SMB as far as I know there isn't another option.

Comment: @KeithLoughnane what are you putting for the url to the server?

Comment: smb:\\<server name>

Comment: @KeithLoughnane updated.

Comment: cifs:// doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I concur with Keith's last answer: File Locking seems to be the root cause. His "solutions" also work for us, but none of those are of course a workable permanent solution.

I have now replicated this problem with Mac OS X 10.6.5 - 10.8.2

I have also verified that this is not a problem with "Named Streams" as described at http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4017.
Creating file ".com.apple.smb.streams.off" at the root of the share does not clear the problem.